# Intonation of "come off it!"

Tags: spoken-english, phonetics

Which part gets a higher stress? The *off*, or the *it*?

> Come OFF it!
>
> Come off IT!

Or the three words are equally stressed?

> COME OFF IT!

Is there a fixed intonation pattern for exclamations, especially three-word ones like this and *lay* *off* *it*?

Comment: "Come ***off*** it!"

Comment: It could be either CO-O-ME off it! or Come OFF it!.  The first intonation could reflect good-natured ribbing between friends (you're full of hot air!), and the second could be impatience or being annoyed (enough already!).

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  As with most expressions you can vary which of the words you stress to emphasize which part is most important in the current context.

That being said, I practiced a few times and, by default, you would stress the "off",

> "Come **OFF** it."

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance under which *Come off **IT**!* would sound natural.